# Initliazing Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Based on the two ways of initializing a Javascript object, which one is the better one and which is faster?

```
// first
options = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2
}

//second
Secoptions = {};
Secoptions.prop1 = 1;
Secoptions.prop2 = 2;

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //based on the two ways of initializing a javascript object
        //which one is the better one and faster 
        // first
        options = {
            prop1: 1,
            prop2: 2
        }

        //second
        Secoptions = {};
        Secoptions.prop1 = 1;
        Secoptions.prop2 = 2;

    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: Define 'better' in context. Though, in all honesty, it **a:** *doesn't really matter*, and, ultimately, comes down to **b:** *what do you find easier to read?*

Comment: You mention "faster"; you can always run a test in http://jsperf.com/ .. I tried to create one for this but it's having some 404 script errors at the moment. I'd be surprised if there's a speed difference; I'd expect it comes down to what's easiest to use and understand.

Answer (score 0):

First option seems to be a little bit faster. In my very old computer with IE6 first one takes about 0.011 milliseconds to complete and second one takes about 0.0131 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on where you are using the variables. If they are being using during loading then first way is better. Honestly speaking performance wise both are same.